# Safari bookmark indicator

Tags: safari

I have recently switched from Chrome to Safari. One thing I am still missing from Safari is a bookmark indicator. As in the Chrome address bar, if the current page has already been bookmarked, the star is yellow.

Are there any other extensions doing this?

I have searched for an extension but failed. I saw the same question from years ago unanswered:

[Safari bookmark indicator](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/safari-bookmark-indicator.1003771/)

[bookmark indicator](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3503919?tstart=0)

Comment: I've changed your title to what I think may better reflect your intent. If you don't feel that was correct, please feel free to revert my edit, or re-word it as you see fit.

Comment: My fault the question was not clear. I have clarified it. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like Apple or Safari dev team totally ignores this feature available in Chrome and Firefox the same as a feature displaying a link address when hovering it with a mouse pointer.